# NSAttributedString: turn (multiple) @username[userid] mentions into clickable @username links

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

I am in the process of writing code to display mentions within an `NSAttributedString`, which need to link out to a user profile. The format of the mentions is `@username[userid]`, which would need to be displayed as simply `@username`, which is tappable.

I have the code working so far that the username becomes clickable, but I now need to remove the `[userid]` part, which of course modifies the length of the string so that ranges don't match anymore, etc. Not sure how I can solve this.

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

let comment = "Hello @kevin[1], @john and @andrew[2]!"

let wholeRange = NSRange(comment.startIndex..<comment.endIndex, in: comment)
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(@[\w.-@]+)\[(\d+)\]"#)

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: comment)

regex.enumerateMatches(in: comment, options: [], range: wholeRange) { match, _, _ in
  guard let match = match else {
    return
  }

  let userIdRange = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: comment)!
  let userId = comment[userIdRange]

  let usernameRange = match.range(at: 1)
  attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: URL(string: "test://profile/\(userId)")!, range: usernameRange)
}

print(attributedString)
```

The result right now can be represented like this, when printed:

```
Hello {
}@kevin{
    NSLink = "test://profile/1";
}[1], @john and {
}@andrew{
    NSLink = "test://profile/2";
}[2]!{
}
```

So `@kevin` and `@andrew` are links, `@john` is not (which is expected!), but the user ids are still visible. Surely this is a problem that has been solved before but I can't find any examples, not sure what keywords to search for. There are plenty of questions about detecting usernames/mentions in strings, and even more about making links in `NSAttributedString`, but that's not the problem I am trying to solve.

How would I turn the `@username[userid]` mentions into clickable `@username` links, so that the `[userid]` part is hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickly done:

```
let comment = "Hello @kevin[1], @john and @andrew[2]!"

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: comment)

let wholeRange = NSRange(attributedString.string.startIndex..<attributedString.string.endIndex, in: attributedString.string)
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(@[\w.-@]+)\[(\d+)\]"#)

let matches = regex.matches(in: attributedString.string, options: [], range: wholeRange)

matches.reversed().forEach { aResult in
    let fullMatchRange = Range(aResult.range(at: 0), in: attributedString.string)!      //@kevin[1]
    let replacementRange = Range(aResult.range(at: 1), in: attributedString.string)!    //@kevin
    let userIdRange = Range(aResult.range(at: 2), in: attributedString.string)!         // 1

    let atAuthor = String(attributedString.string[replacementRange])

    attributedString.addAttribute(.link,
                                  value: URL(string: "test://profile/\(attributedString.string[userIdRange])")!,
                                  range: NSRange(fullMatchRange, in: attributedString.string))
    attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: NSRange(fullMatchRange, in: attributedString.string),
                                       with: atAuthor)
}

print(attributedString)
```

Output:

```
Hello {
}@kevin{
    NSLink = "test://profile/1";
}, @john and {
}@andrew{
    NSLink = "test://profile/2";
}!{
}
```

What's to see:

- I changed the pattern, for easy captures. See the sample in comment in the `forEach()`.
- I used matches in reverse order, else the ranges won't be accurate anymore!
- I kept playing with `attributedString.string` instead of `comment` in case it's "unsync".

Comment: Ah, using matches in reverse order was the lightbulb moment I missed. So easy once it clicks!  I was getting crashes when doing them in normal order.

Comment: Oh, indeed, it was a previous test in my code, and I thought that at first you wanted `@john` to link to `test://profile/john` so I made extra groups/ranges too. But it should be cleaner now.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to get all the matching ranges, iterate them in reverse order, add the link to it and then replace the whole range with the name. Something like:

```
let comment = "Hello @kevin[1], @john and @andrew[2]!"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: comment)
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"(@[\w.-@]+)\[(\d+)\]"#)
var ranges: [(NSRange,NSRange,NSRange)] = []
regex.enumerateMatches(in: comment, range: NSRange(comment.startIndex..., in: comment)) { match, _, _ in
  guard let match = match else {
    return
  }
    ranges.append((match.range(at: 0),
                   match.range(at: 1),
                   match.range(at: 2)))
}

ranges.reversed().forEach {
    let userId = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: $0.2).string
    let username = attributedString.attributedSubstring(from: $0.1).string
    
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: URL(string: "test://profile/\(userId)")!, range: $0.0)
    attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: $0.0, with: username)
}
print(attributedString)
```

This will print

> Hello {
> }@kevin{
> NSLink = "test://profile/1";
> }, @john and {
> }@andrew{
> NSLink = "test://profile/2";
> }!{
> }